# Does the Earth's moon have a moon of it's own?

Tags: astronomy

Out of simple curiosity, does anybody know if any searches have been done to check on the possibility that the earth's moon has a moon of it's own?

Excluding man made objects, of course.

I would be 99.999% percent certain it has not, down to a small scale, or we would have detected it by now, and that also NASA would have examined the volume of space around the moon carefully before the Apollo manned missions.

Comment: Sure. The moon can have satellites of its own, they are usually just short lived. We have a couple of them up there, right now. There are Earth-Moon Lagrange points that are stable, if you are willing to accept the debris that sits in there as "moons", then the moon does have, sort of, natural moons of its own. I am pretty sure that there are many small objects that are also in shorter lived orbits all the time.

Comment: Why are you excluding man made objects? Does it matter to the moon's physics, whether the stuff that is caught in its gravity has an "Oskar Kaiser" on it or not? :-)

Comment: Yeah, looked that up previously, Seems to be mostly dust, actually, if it was old, old early solar system dust, it would be very interesting, and relatively easy enough to send up a sample  collector mission, easier than waiting for a comet.

Comment: I have no idea about dust, but I believe that large bodies are not doing well in the gravity field of the moon as there seem to be few, if any, stable orbits.

Comment: Oops, apologies, I was trying to make a joke and it misfired. :-) "OTTO Kaiser" was supposedly a guy who put "OK" on his products and that's one of the more unlikely etymologies (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proposed_etymologies_of_OK) for our current quality control "OK" stamp. A man made satellite comes with thousands those (but maybe none stamped on the actual product). :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne  re our comments a few days ago, I have posted this on the meta, any edits or improvements would be welcome http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6852/why-does-the-question-box-not-ask-at-what-level-are-you-at-in-study